# fread is not reading the columns names properly

Tags: r, csv, import, download, data.table

I am trying to use a csv generated from the Apple mobility reports, which can be found [here](https://covid19.apple.com/mobility).

Now everything works relatively fine, and I am able to get the .csv as intended, which looks something like this text:

```
csvtxt <- "geo_type,region,2020-01-14,2020-01-15,2020-01-16
country/region,Albania,50.1,100.2,75.3"
```

But when I `fread` it, the first line, which is unsurprisingly a column name line, is not recognized as so, even with the option `check.names = FALSE` that I found somewhere here but cannot find again.

```
library(data.table)
fread(csvtxt, check.names = FALSE)
#               V1      V2         V3         V4         V5
#1:       geo_type  region 2020-01-14 2020-01-15 2020-01-16
#2: country/region Albania       50.1      100.2       75.3
```

Is there a way to get this data to import so that the column name line is recognized properly?

Comment: Can you skip all the `curl` download parts and reduce the problem to a couple of lines of csv that do not work as expected with `fread`? If everything up to that point works fine, it's probably not needed to be included in the question, and will make the issue more generic for future readers.

Comment: Sorry if my question is stupid but it has been a long day. I am not sure of the best way to do what you suggest, as I can either get the full cvs (which is also in the link at the beginning), or dput the datatable I get, but that probably leads to a loss of information from what data I got it ?

Comment: Your code works fine for me, `fread(paste0(Chemin,"AMR","_",today(),".csv"), header = TRUE)` (R version 4.0.2, data.table_1.13.2) You need to force it by setting to TRUE, as you have *"invalid"* names.

Comment: @zx8754 I guess I just was not able to read the documentation properly... Thanks

Comment: @AnthonyMartin - I've made an attempt at an edit simplifying the issue to the core of your problem. Can you check if it is okay please?

Comment: @thelatemail nice, is it now worth adding an answer, or close as read the docs?

Comment: @zx8754 - I think it's worth adding the answer - I didn't know this issue or the way to resolve it so at least one person will find it beneficial.

Comment: @thelatemail It is perfectly clear, and now I feel I have made you do my work. Thank you

Comment: @zx8754 I think it is, I was convinced it was the default parameter

Comment: @AnthonyMartin - all good :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to force the header by setting it to TRUE.

```
library(data.table) # R version 4.0.2, data.table_1.13.2

fread(csvtxt, header = TRUE)
#          geo_type  region 2020-01-14 2020-01-15 2020-01-16
# 1: country/region Albania       50.1      100.2       75.3
```

From the manuals:

> **header**
> Does the first data line contain column names? Defaults according to whether every non-empty field on the first data line is
> type character. If so, or TRUE is supplied, any empty column names are
> given a default name.

Confusion might be from *read.csv* where header is TRUE by default:

```
read.csv(text = csvtxt)
#         geo_type  region X2020.01.14 X2020.01.15 X2020.01.16
# 1 country/region Albania        50.1       100.2        75.3
```

Comment: I think the trap here is that there are column names not containing any letters. If I change the file to have `"A2020-01-14,A2020-01-15,A2020-01-16"` it works just fine.

Comment: @thelatemail yes, noticed that, too. Manuals wording is not very clear to me. I checked the source code of fread, looks like header "guessing" is done using *yaml* package.

Comment: Feel free to edit with further details. To me "2020-01-15" is a valid "character" type string.

Comment: Yaml package is not used for guessing headers, it is used for getting headers if they are provided in yaml header inside csv (aka CSVY). If no yaml header is in csv then I would expect guessing happens somewhere in C.

Comment: @jangorecki Thank you, wasn't sure how to word it, please feel free to edit to add more detail.